# Controlling number of instances of one object in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, instance

Upon touching screen, the method

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

creates an instance of a SKSpriteNode. Every touch creates another one. By using a sequence of SKActions, I've made newly-created sprites to fade out after a short moment to not over-run the scene with too many nodes. The only thing I want to add to the code now is the ability for SKSpriteNode's to appear upon touch ONLY AFTER the previous one has been removed from the scene. So until the previous SKSpriteNode is removed, the user can touch the screen all they want and not a single one will appear. I've tried using an IF statement but it hasn't worked:

```
if (self.children.count == 0)
    {
        [self addChild:self.object];
    }
```

Comment: Probably because self already has more than one child node. In any case that code will break if it does. Instead, save the instance to a __weak ivar and check whether it's nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean flag

```
bool canSpawn = YES;
```

Check on touch:

```
if(canSpawn == YES)
{
    //Spawn node
    canSpawn = NO;       
}
```

Because you use a sequence, the canSpawn will be set to no essentially at the same time you start your sequence.

End your sequence with a runBlock SKAction that sets `canSpawn = YES;`  This way, you cannot spawn while canSpawn is set to NO, which occurs only when you have spawned a node that has not vanished yet.  Once it vanishes, your canSpawn gets set to YES which allows you to make another sprite.